# How to find all maximum independent sets in an iterative way?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The following code can find all the maximum independent sets of a graph `lg` **at once**.

```
g = Graph[
   ImportString["W|tNHEpCKoh`@@Po_WHB@CKC?WGO{G?KKCB`?OMG?_y_?Sn", 
    "Graph6"], VertexLabels -> Automatic];
lg = LineGraph[g]
FindIndependentVertexSet[lg, 
 Length /@ FindIndependentVertexSet[lg], All]
Length[%]
```

```
Out[*] 340649
```

However, it uses up 81.8Mb of memory.  I wonder if there is **some iterative way** to generate them. I don't see the option. The main reason is to save some memory costs or for having some flexibility.

---

I know that [independent polynomials][1] can give the number  of maximum independent sets. But *Mathematica* doesn't seem to have a function for this. This is mainly to check the correctness of the *Mathematica* calculation from another view.

**Edits:** I checked with the codes in the link below and the results given by mathematica are correct.

- https://github.com/pernici/hobj

The coefficients of the independent polynomial of `lg` are as follows.

```
[340649, 12329124, 68797662, 140606548, 139481127, 77027880, 25546428, 5303544, 700911, 58580, 2982, 84, 1]
```

---

I have an open attitude towards code that is not written in Mathematica. Actually, this is a quite common issue, because many Mathematica functions that set to "all" do not provide an iteration option, which is unreasonable.

Comment: I am not aware of a fully general way to generate independent vertex sets iteratively. If you want to count them only, you can use `IGMaximalCliqueSizeCounts` or `IGCliqueSizeCounts` on the complementer graph.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you very much for your attention to my question. I am very curious, many Mathematica functions do have a lot of ALL options, for example, `FindShortestPath` , `FindGraphIsomorphism` and so on. But I have almost never seen a setting for iteration options, which can be very frustrating, especially when the number is relatively large.